# Get item before filter match

Tags: scala

To filter a list of items I use :

```
  val l : List[String] = List("1","a","2","b")

  l.filter(c => c.contains("b")).foreach(println)
```

But how can I access the items that occur before the matched item ? So in this case "2" is accessed ?

Update :

```
 List("1","a","2","b","3","b","4","b")
filtering on "b" returns 
List("2","3","4")
filtering on "a" returns
List("1")
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? What should the result be for `val l = List("1", "2", "b", "3", "b", "b")`?

Comment: @Kolmar does update make it clearer ? val l = List("1", "2", "b", "3", "b", "b") should just return List("2","3","b")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
val x = l.tail.foldLeft(l.head, (List.empty[(String, String)]))((x,c) => if(c.contains("b")) (c, (x._1, c):: x._2) else (c, x._2))._2

val ans = if(l.head.contains("b")) (null, l.head.contains("b")) :: x    else x
```

Gives you output as `List((2,b))`.

Answer (score 3):

if you are looking for list of all items that appear just before item-that-contains-"b":

```
def prevItems(l: List[String]) = 
  l.sliding(2)
   .filter{ case List(a, b, _*) => b.contains("b"); case _ => false }
   .map{ x => x(0) }
   .toList

val list1 = List("1","a","2","b")
prevItems(list1)
// List(2)

val list2 = List("b", "a", "b")
prevItems(list2)
// List(a)

val list3 = List("1", "2", "b", "3", "b", "b")
prevItems(list3)
// List(2, 3, b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your description is a bit cryptic, but I think you want a list of the elements that appear before the first match - e.g., all elements before the first element that contains "b".

If so, use `takeWhile`

```
scala> val l = List("1","a","2","b")
l: List[String] = List(1, a, 2, b)

scala> l takeWhile {! _.contains("b")}
res0: List[String] = List(1, a, 2)
```

If you want the element that appears right before the first element that contains "b":

```
scala> l.takeWhile{! _.contains("b")}.last
res1: String = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

code:

```
 val list = List("1", "2", "b", "3", "b", "b")

 list.zip(list.tail).filter(p=>p._2 .equalsIgnoreCase("b") ).foreach(f=>println(f._1))
```

Answer (score 0):

How to do this using sliding and flatMap.

```
val list = List("1", "2", "b", "3", "b", "b")
val target = "b"
list.sliding(2).flatMap{ 
   case Seq(x,y) => if(y == target) Some(x) else None 
   case _ => None
}.toSeq
```